# Not able to setup keyStore( .p12 extension) in Liberty

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

### I am using IBMJSSE2 provider in my enterprise application.

I am migrating from websphere 8.5 to Liberty 8.5.
So Can I use? .p12 file which I got from websphere installed location inside appsvr01

- If yes then how to use it in  tag of  server.xml(liberty)

-If no then can we generate our own keystore using IBMJSSE2 standard in liberty.Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes
Did you checked the doc [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_sec_keystores.html) ?

```
<keyStore id="samplePKCS12KeyStore"
          location="MyKeyStoreFile.p12"
          type="PKCS12" 
          password="myPassword" />
```

Comment: DO I need to import MyKeyStoreFile.p12 from somewhere or it will be created automatically on mentioning it in server.xml  and starting the server

Comment: From the same doc: `PKCS12 keystore
Public Key Cryptography Standards #12 (PKCS12) keystore can be used, but not created by Liberty`

Comment: Liberty will not create a PKCS12 keystore.  But will use one that you created using some other tool.